# Chocolatey setup on USB drive

Tags: windows, chocolatey

I'm trying to set up Chocolatey for the first time. My ultimate goal is to be able to install the packages on a USB drive which shows up in my computer as F: so following [the directions in the Chocolatey wiki](https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/Installation), I created a folder on the F drive called Chocolatey and set an environmental variable ChocolateyInstall to `F:/Chocolatey`. I followed the basic directions, by opening up a command prompt and then pasting in the following.

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%systemdrive%\chocolatey\bin
```

After installation I went to the PowerShell command prompt as follows and tried to install Notepad++ I got the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cinst notepadplusplus
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you went to a custom location with Chocolatey's install. When it finished the install, did it say it was installed on F:/chocolatey? Is it actually installed there? If so, take a look at your path environment variable and see if that is included in the path. Also close and reopen the shell/command line. Does it work now? If the path (user PATH) has the choco location in it and the shell/command line is not proper after reloading, then reboot and see if that fixes the issue.

If all of that is good, type just `chocolatey /?` and see what you get. Then try `cinst` again. If it has issues again, try `cinst pkgname -debug` and see where the error happens.

NOTE: Trying to install Chocolatey to a USB drive is not a supported case. Sure you might be able to get it to work but I'm not sure what you really gain. Say you install Notepad++, now it is installed to the system (not the USB drive). What do you gain by having the choco repository on the USB drive?

Comment: I appreciate your answer. based on https://github.com/chocolatey/chocolatey/wiki/DefaultChocolateyInstallReasoning, I assumed that where you said "Chocolatey should be able to be installed on a machine where the user does not have administrative rights." - which is commonly my situation , I would be able to put things on a USB. I like having an entire environment set up on a USB drive, which I can easily move. Do you plan to make this a future use case? Regards, Bill

Comment: While chocolatey can work with non-administrative, that doesn't mean that every package can. If you are strict about the packages you bring in and know that you will need to add the choco path to the PATH on all machines, you will probably be fine to do it that way.

Comment: "that you will need to add the choco path to the PATH on all machines" - ConEmu !?

Comment: Well, what I will gain is a portable command line tool to install software on many different PCs. At least that's the goal.